# Mi condición no muestra valores negativos entre 0 y -1 en reportes rdlc de .net en c#

Tags: visual-studio, .net, reportviewer, rdlc

En los reportes .rdlc (report viewer) de visual studio 2019, añado una condición para que uno de los campo decimales del reporte no se muestre en caso de que su valor sea 0.

```
<Value>=IIf(Val(Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)=0,"",Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)</Value>
```

Hasta aquí funciona bien, el valor se muestra solo cuando su valor es distinto de 0. Pero hay una pequeña casuística en la que no funciona bien y no se muestra cuando debería mostrarse.

Esta casuística se dá cuando la fluctuación tiene un valor negativo comprendido entre 0 y -1, por ejemplo: -0,2   Si el valor de fluctuiación es -0,2 no se muestra cuando debería de mostrarse porque 0,2 es distinto de 0.

¿Alguien se ha encontrado con este problema? ¿Cómo lo ha solucionado?

Muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Comment: Que caso más particular ese.
Y si intentas colocando 0.0
A lo mejor funcione

Comment: Nada, con 0.0 no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Solo cambiando el operador de comparación lo resuelves.

En tu caso solo cambiando:

```
<Value>=IIf(Val(Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)=0,"",Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)</Value>
```

Por:

```
<Value>=IIf(Val(Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)<=0,"",Fields!Fluctuacion.Value)</Value>
```

Con esto debería funcionar.

Saludos.